# MFC CtreeCtrl CustomDraw CDIS_HOT change font style failed

Tags: mfc, underline, custom-draw

In customdraw the MFC CTreeCtrl ,I want to remove the font text underline when  item is in hot state,so the code is like :

```
void CTreeCtrlCS::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
            ...........................
            ........................... 

            CFont       *pCurFont = NULL;
            CFont       *pNewFont = NULL;
            LOGFONT     logfont;

            /* Draw Hot State */
            if (itemState & CDIS_HOT) {
                printf ("step A \n");
                pCurFont = dc.GetCurrentFont ();
                printf ("step B \n");
                memset ((void *) &logfont,0,sizeof (logfont));
                printf ("step C \n");
                pCurFont->GetLogFont (&logfont);
                printf ("step D \n");
                logfont.lfUnderline = 0;  /* remove the underline */
                pCurFont->DeleteObject ();
                printf ("step E \n");
                pCurFont->CreateFontIndirect (&logfont);
                printf ("step F \n");
                dc.SelectObject (pCurFont);
                printf ("step G \n");
            } else {
                ;
            }
            printf ("end draw \n");
            ..................
}
```

when on ***Debug Version*** ,the application crash ,and the console shows

[image]

I didn't use multi-thread ,it's very very strange . 
Desired show is

StepA
stepB
...
end draw

stepA
stepB
end draw

But the situation is most likely that the CDIS_HOT case re-entered ...
I don't understand why would this happen ?

By the way,
***what is the correct way to remove the text under line when item is in hot state (CDIS_HOT) ？***

any help appreciated .

Comment: [CDC::GetCurrentFont](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/242xhdxx.aspx) returns a **pointer** to the same font object that is currently selected into your device context. It is owned by the framework. You are not responsible for disposing it, and most certainly not while it is selected into a device context.

Comment: thks ,You just point out the key error ,
I used a CFont to store the 'new' font that changed from currentfont 
Now it is Ok now .....
thks....

Answer (score 0):

```
    CFont       *pCurFont = NULL;
    CFont       *pNewFont = NULL;
    CFont       *pOldFont = NULL;
    LOGFONT     logfont;
    CFont       newfont ;

    /* Draw Hot State */
    if (itemState & CDIS_HOT) {
        pCurFont = dc.GetCurrentFont ();
        if (pCurFont)  {
            memset ((void *) &logfont,0,sizeof (logfont));
            if (pCurFont->GetLogFont (&logfont)) {
                logfont.lfUnderline = 0;
                logfont.lfHeight = pRect->bottom - pRect->top - 3;
                logfont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
                newfont.CreateFontIndirect (&logfont);
                pOldFont = dc.SelectObject (&newfont);
            }
        }
    } else {
        ;
    }
```

Now.It's OK now ...

Comment: `newfont` gets destroyed, when it goes out of scope. If this is all the code you have, you are destroying an object that is still selected into a device context.

Comment: Yes ,it's just a part of my code ,oldfont will be selected back to dc...

thks